# How to show / validate error of a node listing page

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms, drupal-nodes

i am trying to save form state in database and want to view in a listing page with its error validation.

i.e, i want to validate a previously saved form state from my database.

this is a node type form .

i had already tried `node_validate` its not working because i fetch the data before submitting the node . so there is no nid and for that it is not working

and also tried  `drupal_validate_form` but it is showing

```
[form_token] => The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page
```

**EDIT**
Any one with any help , "How to save a form inputs in data base and retrive it from database with out form submision.

Thank You In advance

Any help is most Appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in Drupal Core, you see this in `includes/form.inc` at the `drupal_validate_form` function:

```
if (isset($form['#token'])) {
    if (!drupal_valid_token($form_state['values']['form_token'], $form['#token'])) {
      $path = current_path();
      $query = drupal_get_query_parameters();
      $url = url($path, array('query' => $query));

      // Setting this error will cause the form to fail validation.
      form_set_error('form_token', t('The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then <a href="@link">reload this page</a>.', array('@link' => $url)));

      // Stop here and don't run any further validation handlers, because they
      // could invoke non-safe operations which opens the door for CSRF
      // vulnerabilities.
      $validated_forms[$form_id] = TRUE;
      return;
    }
  }`
```

This shows that the "form has become outdated" message is being set here. So, you can make the `isset($form[#token'])` condition false by unsetting `#token` to prevent this message from appearing.

All you have to do is load the form state you're going to validate, and call
`unset($form[#token']);` before you call `drupal_validate_form`.

Comment: thank you for yor reply but i already solve that and yes unset the #token make it

Comment: can you just tell me why drupal_validate_form not executes required field validation